# Problem with converting a Project to TIBCO BusinessWorks™ Container Edition

Tags: docker, tibco, tibco-business-works

I am trying to convert a project from its original edition to the bwce as below link

https://docs.tibco.com/pub/bwce/2.4.1/doc/html/GUID-21D006B3-E8D0-47B1-A376-89457FA0BCD7.html

But, when I chose Repair BusinessWork project, it doesn't have the option like the link "Convert projects to current edition"

Please see my attached file [image]

I am using the version: TIBCO Business Studio for BusinessWorks(TM)

Version: 2.4.2
Built on Eclipse Platform Version: 4.4.1

Answer (score 0):

do you see any error of incompatibility of your project with the current version in the Problems tab ?

if not your project is ready no conversion is needed.

from the documentation 
https://docs.tibco.com/pub/bwce/2.4.1/doc/html/GUID-154DF126-D1B1-4773-A19E-3EF281693D24.html

> A new validation has been added to check whether your project was created using the TIBCO BusinessWorks™ Container Edition. If the validation fails, an error marker displays in the Problems view, describing the validation and how to fix it.

Comment: Yes, there is a problem "Description Resource Path Location Type
Module configuration error. The BusinessWorks module [Tibco] has no process to execute. module.bwm /Tibco/META-INF platform:/resource/Tibco/META-INF/module.bwm#_n8m7kD9cEemeBJCqWLuDhA EMF Validation Problems"

Comment: here you need juste to add a process starter to your project or if already exist you need to configure the Components tab in module discriptors

Answer (score 0):

The documentation link you provide is for version 2.4.1
Your version is 2.4.2.

It's not clear to me if you are converting a BW6 project, or BWCE project created with an older version, anyway with the current version of BW (and it's true also for BWCE 2.4.2) the IDE is the same(build ones, deploy everywere).

Same version of business studio is used to develop BW6, BWCE and TCI BW applications.
The runtime target (Appspace ->BW6, Container - BWCE, Cloud -> TCI) is just a a setting in Business studio.
In your case it's enough to import the project in Studio to see if there are any errors.